# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'Link')

Tags: javascript, html

[When i try to run the fucntion, it keeps saying"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'Link')"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xujJY.png)

Comment: Have you tried adding a `console.log(snapshot)` before the failing line? Just to see what the value of snapshot is

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove in line 99 the slash. Small note: Code would be better as an image with code.
`getelementbyid("namebox")...`

Comment: Also my PC crashed when retrieving code from the image.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help. It already take me one day trying to figure it out

Comment: You welcome @user17373203 :-) It was helpfull it would be nice if you can accept the answear. The check mark under the vote button.

Comment: Sorry for the late accept. Im new to stackoverflow so im still trying it out